# SkiaSharp and Xamarin.Forms - unable to decode png

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, skiasharp

When using the following code in a PCL, I get an `ArgumentNullException` for parameter name `codec`.

```
using (var stream = new SKFileStream("image.png"))
using (var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream)) { 
    ...
}
```

The exception is thrown in `SKBitmap.Decode`. I can verify that the image is a valid PNG file and that the stream's length is greater than 0.

Do I need to install codecs separately or something? I don't see anything about it in the samples.

Comment: Are you able to share the full exception? And if possible the PNG? And, do any other PNGs work?

Comment: SkiaSharp includes all the codecs, so nothing extra is needed.

Comment: @Matthew - Thanks for your input, you pointed me in the right direction. See my answer below. You're on the SkiaSharp team, correct? Perhaps support for pngcrush'd images could be added in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By disabling PNG optimization (pngcrush) under iOS Build settings, I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sadly, this is Google's response: "It's a proprietary png format only supported by iOS.  We don't have plans to support this"
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/skia-discuss/png$20ios%7Csort:relevance/skia-discuss/nbRQI7pfqbw/go5v1nF6CwAJ

Comment: Bummer. Thanks again for your help.